# c++ variable assignment makes code work

Tags: c++, visual-c++, constructor, variable-assignment

I have a class:
Register.h

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class Register {
public:
    Register(const std::string& name);
    void printName();

private:
    const std::string& m_name;
};
```

Register.cpp:

```
#include "Register.h"
#include <iostream>

Register::Register(const std::string& name) : m_name(name) {
}

void Register::printName() {
    std::cout << m_name << std::endl;
}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "Register.h"

int main() {
    const std::string name1 = "A";
    Register reg1(name1);
    reg1.printName();

    Register reg2("A");
    reg2.printName();

    getchar();
}
```

I would expect this to print "A" twice, however it prints `"A"` once and `""` once.  Please could you tall me the difference between the two options and how I could get the second to work, as I don't use `name` any where else in the function that creates `reg`?

Comment: There's not enough information why the second version shouldn't work equally well. Can you provide a [MCVE] that reproduces the behavior you claim please.

Comment: What is `m_name` ? reference  :/ ?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, I have updated the question to add a better example

Comment: @ComputerBackup After the `Register reg2("A");` `m_name` contains a dangling reference (a reference to an object, that is destroyed), and using such reference, in any way, invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to use reference member variables. You have to be *very* careful about lifetime of the object you initialize the reference from in such a case.

Comment: Would it be better to just pass the string by value instead, make it a `const std::string`?

Comment: @ComputerBackup If you still stored a reference - you would face the same problem: reference bound to a temporary, which is destroyed at the end of the statement. The problem is not due to how you are passing the value, but due to how you are storing it inside the class.

Comment: @ComputerBackup The `const string&` for the constructor parameter is just fine, but your member variable should be a simple `std::string`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using

```
Register reg2("A");
```

implicitly creates a temporary `std::string` instance, and you initialize a reference member variable from it:

```
const std::string& m_name;

Register::Register(const std::string& name) : m_name(name) {
}
```

Lifetime of the temporary instance ends after the constructor call, and you have a dangling reference afterwards, accessing it is undefined behavior.

The initialization from a variable ensures that the reference is valid as long the variable is in scope and active.

---

To fix that problem simply make the `m_name` member variable a normal `string` instead of a `const` reference.

```
std::string m_name;
```